How to have a ReactShinyInput inside a ReactShinyWidget?
I have just started playing with the reactR package in the hope of having React elements usable with Shiny R.
I have got project with the scaffoldReactWidget function setup and working quite nicely so far with the reactflow react library.
The next part that I want to accomplish is to add react buttons to the project and I am using scaffoldReactShinyInput to do that (as described here) inside the same project.
This fails. I found that if scaffoldReactShinyInput is called inside the project created and used for scaffoldReactWidget the following error appears after runApp():

Warning: Error in value[[3L]]: Couldn't normalize path in
addResourcePath, with arguments: prefix =
'action_button-input-1.0.0'; directoryPath = ''

I think the reason is that the scaffoldReactShinyInput does not create a www directory with action_button.js script in it.
I think that I am doing something wrong here in terms of workflow.
Should I create separate projects for each instance of calling the scaffold... functions? And then source-created packages in a master project?
Please help with the explanation. I could not find any general tutorial that goes beyond creating and interacting with a single react input or widget. I want to use react inputs inside the react widget in Shiny.

To reproduce do the following in RStudio:
# make "reactflow" directory and set working directory to it (directory name matters)

usethis::create_package(getwd())

# this opens up a new RStudio session.
# In the newly opened session:

reactR::scaffoldReactWidget("reactflow", list("@xyflow/react" = "^12.0.1"), edit = FALSE)
system("yarn install")
system("yarn run webpack --mode=development")
devtools::document()
devtools::load_all()
shiny::runApp()

The above set of actions creates boilerplate app and you should see "reactR HTMLWidget Example" "Hello world!"
Widget is done.
Next I am adding reactShinyInput:
reactR::scaffoldReactShinyInput("action_button", list("reactstrap" = "^8.9.0"))
system("yarn install")
system("yarn run webpack --mode=development")
devtools::document()
devtools::load_all()

Add action_buttonInput to ui in app.R.
'app.R' looks like below:
library(shiny)
library(reactflow)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("reactR HTMLWidget Example"),
  reactflowOutput('widgetOutput'),
  action_buttonInput('action_button')
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$widgetOutput <- renderReactflow(
    reactflow("Hello world!")
  )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)

Now run the app (runApp()).

Warning: Error in value[[3L]]: Couldn't normalize path in addResourcePath, with arguments: prefix = 'action_button-input-1.0.0'; directoryPath = ''
1: runApp


You have a better chance of getting definitive advice if you provide a minimal reproducible example.  I'm not familiar with reactR, but the title of your post suggests that you might be nesting reactives.  In my experience, that never turns out well.

Thank you. I added the steps to reproduce in the original post
